# How to load a list of strings into code that requires a list of strings seperated by commas

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that requires a list of strings separated by commas. Here is the partial code:

```
Dim sailnums = New String() {var(0), var(1), var(2), var(3), var(4), var(5), var(6), var(7), var(8), var(9)}
    Dim recog As New SpeechRecognitionEngine()
    recog.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
    Dim nums As New Choices(sailnums)
    Dim gram As Grammar = New Grammar(New GrammarBuilder(nums))
    recog.LoadGrammar(gram)
    RemoveHandler recog.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf recog_SpeechRecognized
    AddHandler recog.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf recog_SpeechRecognized
    recog.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)
```

This code works, however I don't know ahead of time how many strings identified in my cade as var(index number) I will need. I would like to be able to insert a variable that I could place between the curly braces that would insert the complete list of strings separated by commas identified by var(0) thru var(max number of strings). Is this possible, and if so how do I do it.

Comment: Use a [`List(of String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead.  All the power, none of the trouble of arrays.

Comment: is `Dim s As String() = SomeStringVariable.Split(",")` what you are looking for?

Comment: if you just want to copy `var` in its current state so it wont be changed if you change `var` you can use `Dim s As String() = SomeStringÀrray.Clone`

Comment: The var(0), var(1), var(2) etc. are strings resulting from a list of strings. The problem is there may be 5 or 15 strings, and the list as you see in the code must match the number of strings in the list so it would be nice to have a variable that inserts all of the strings from the list into the line of code Dim sailnums = New String() {var(0), var(1), var(2)}. Converting the list of strings into one large string does not work. It must be the complete list of the individual strings separated by commas. Something like: varlist As List = (var(0), var(1), var(2)) would be nice

Comment: when creating a variable like this, the number of items inside the {} specify the amount of items the array has. if you want to create an array with a specific size you need to know the size first ( you might get it like this:) `Dim sailnums(var.GetUpperBound(0)) As String` and then set the value of each arrayitem. Or you create an array without a size and then fill it with an array with a specifc size like i showed you in the comment showing how to clone an stringarray

Answer (score 0):

Does `Choices` need to require a String array as it's input? You say you need a comma separated list, but I don't see where you use one/need one. Not to mention you say what you have works other than not handling the unknown array length.

Assuming `sailnums` works as-is (other than the length issue), I'm with Plutonix, seems like your best bet is to use `Dim sailnums as New List(of String)` and set it with

```
For i as Integer = 0 to var.Length-1
    sailnums.Add(var(i))
Next
```

and then make the appropriate updates to `Choices` to use the List instead of an array (which is what it's using right now).

Alternatively, if you really do need `sailnums` to be a string you would use

```
Dim sailnums as String

For i as Integer = 0 to var.Length-1
    'Make sure we don't add a comma before the first item
    If sailnums.length > 0 then
        sailnums = sailnums & ", " & var(i)
    Else
        sailnums = var(i)
    End If
Next
```

Lastly, if `sailnums` is fine as an array, then there's no point to `sailnums` just change `Dim nums As New Choices(sailnums)` to `Dim nums as New Choices(var)` and cut out the middle-man.